# How to change file name before loading data using SSIS

Tags: ssis

3rd Friday of every month I receive the excel file name with "excelfilename_date".
I want to give static file name say "excelfilename" and then load the data.
Can someone please suggest how to do that using SSIS?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow  [tour]. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [mcve] applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. Add the code you're using and the details of the errors or exceptions you might have.

Comment: Use a ForEach(file) and assign the filename to a variable. Make sure to delay validation on source as well.